# output in browser not right

Tags: php, file-io

my browser is showing this as a result from the following code (code comes straight out of my course)

rule $lineNr: ". htmlspecialchars($line)."
    "); } ?> 
    (this is not code in my editor this is the actual output of the browser)

```
<?
   // read file in table

   $table = file("test.txt");
   while(list($lineNr, $line) = each($table))
   {
      print("<b>rule $lineNr: </b>". htmlspecialchars($line)."<br>");
   }
?>
```

normally this is because I put my address in my browser the wrong way. But this time the path to the file is rooted in the actual xampp rootfolder just like other php files that do work. So I don't really know where to look for the solution to this.

Comment: Whats the problem? What doesnt work?

Comment: the problem is it says 

rule $lineNr: ". htmlspecialchars($line)." "); } ?> 

in my browser instad of what's contained in the print statement

Comment: I think you should provide some actual code. Could be that your php isn't enabled, or php short tags is not enabled or something else.

Comment: short tags. Try using <?php instead of <?

Comment: Does it output multiple times, or just once? You'd have to find out if its the print statement, or just PHP isnt recognised at all. Try a simple echo statement.

Comment: yes that's it. the browser obviously doesn't tolerate the short tag. allright thanks

Comment: Although that might have fixed your problem, your explanation is wrong. The browser doesnt do anything with php, its the server that didnt recognise the PHP short tags. The server parses your code before it is send to the browser.

Comment: @jack-anyway - it's not the browser, it's PHP. The browser renders exactly what it's told to render by your script... but a browser sees <? and treats it as an unknown html tag, so it doesn't display anything moe until it sees the closing >. That is standard browser behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the full php start tag ("<?php"). You are using the short tag ("<?").

```
<?php

    // code

?>
```